# What is the purpose of the getId and setId methods of Varien_Object? And what value should I pass?

Tags: magento-1.9

In many constructors, for example `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid`, there is a call to `setId()`. I've traced this back up the hierarchy and found it defined in `Varien_Object`.

I've subclassed `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` and found that if I don't call `setId` in the constructor, my code doesn't work, but if I call it, its does. Rather than blindly copying core code, I'd like to understand what the purpose of the `id` of an object is any why code needs it.

Also I'd like to know what value to pass when I call `setId`. I assume there is some sort of naming convention, but I haven't been able to infer one from the core classes.

Comment: Magento collections are made up of models which are essentially rows in your database. I don't really have a complete answer but you can dive more into what makes a Magento Model  at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-5.html

Comment: @asherrard. I don't think the getId and setId have anything to do with Models or the database. The methods are defined on the fundamental Varien object, which pretty much everything inherits from, not just on models, or collections.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, almost every class is based on `Varien_Object` in Magento.

**The row data:**

`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` uses the `Varien_Data_Collection` to handle the row objects (which are instances of `Varien_Object`). Its a combination of the grid and the collection that expects each row object to have a unique ID and 99.9% of the time, its a numeric value.

**The grid subclass:**

The Grid ID is something else entirely... you have IDs such as "cmsPageGrid" for `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Grid`, "sales_order_grid" for `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid`, etc.

If you dive into the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` class you can see that the ID `$this->getId()` is used multiple times for sub-elements, which may generate an unexpected result when ID is unset.

In additional other child elements might be using the Grid ID for their own element ID.